# Using Wercker CLI for build and deploy

Tags: command-line-interface, wercker

I have a Wercker application configured on the Wercker website and their pipelines `build` and `deploy` work fine.

Right now, I have a problem with the deployment and I'm trying to do the same using Wercker CLI. These are the steps I'm following:

```
$ wercker build
--> No Docker host specified, checking: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
--> Executing pipeline
--> Running step: setup environment
[...]
--> Steps passed: 154.70s
--> Pipeline finished: 155.70s
$ wercker deploy --deploy-target stage
--> No Docker host specified, checking: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
--> Executing pipeline
--> Running step: setup environment
[...]
--> Running step: setup configuration files
bash: config-setup.sh: No such file or directory
--> Step failed: setup configuration files 0.81s
--> Pipeline failed: 43.98s
WARNING Box container has already stopped.
FATAL Step failed: setup configuration files
```

On the last steps of the `build` pipeline, I left some files (including `config-setup.sh`) on the `$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR` (its value is `/pipeline/output`). Those files are used on the `deploy` pipeline. **This works on the Wercker website, but it does not work for Wercker CLI.**

I think that I'm missing some parameter to let the `deploy` pipeline know where are the files saved on `$WERCKER_OUTPUT_DIR`. Could you help me, please?

**EDIT:** I simulated manually the execution of the `build` pipeline and save the files on the same source code folder. After that, I could run `wercker deploy`. Of course, this is only a workaround.

Comment: Can you include your wercker.yml file? My guess is the environment variables are resolved...